# How to make created_at and updated_at fields in MsSQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, date, timestamp

I want to make `created_at` and `updated_at` in MsSQL.

Here is query:

```
CREATE TABLE current_timestamp_demos
(
    id         INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    msg        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
);
```

With `created_at` everything is fine, but on filed `updated_at` - here, `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` I get an error. DataGrip say something about dialect, and this is `MySQL` dialect, I guess.

So, how can I create those `created_at` and `updated_at` fields? I've created `created_at`, but with `updated_at` I have some problems.

Comment: By default updated_at column value will NULL. But during update row updated_at column  value will be updated with current_timestamp by query.

Comment: I think, when you add record `created_at` and `updated_at` will have the same value, but when you update it, `updated_at` will change. But it doesn't really matter here, it's about this statement `DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` doesn't work here, it's MySQL dialekt, not what I need (MsSQL)

Comment: Don't use TIMESTAMP. It is actually [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Also note that `The timestamp syntax is deprecated.` Use `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2`

Comment: `SQL Server` does not support `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. You need to update the column value manually in your query or alternatively do it via the update trigger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complete code :

```
CREATE TABLE current_timestamp_demos
(
    id         INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    msg        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATETIME(),
    updated_at DATETIME2 
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER E_U_CTD
ON current_timestamp_demos
FOR UPDATE
AS
UPDATE T
SET updated_at = SYSDATETIME()
FROM   current_timestamp_demos AS T
       JOIN inserted AS i
          ON T.id = i.id;
GO
```

Also use SYSDATETIME() instaed of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.